# preventing dpkg-buildpackage using /usr/bin as installation destination

Tags: debian, package-management, python, dpkg, deb

Briefly, I am building a Debian package. Everything works fine with packaging except the point, that after packaging my application is always in the `/usr/bin` folder.

It's actually a Python application with following setup.py:

```
setup(name="myapp",
      version="0.80.04",
      description='My Appicantion.',
      author='ajava',
      author_email='info@ajava.de',
      url='http://http://www.ajava.de',
      scripts=['myapp'])
```

I have already made an install-file in my `debian` folder.

## /debian/install

```
myapp root/apps/myapp
readme* root/apps/myapp
```

What I get currently is a Debian package with this structure:

```
|
|->usr/bin/myapp
|->root/apps/myapp
|->root/apps/readme  
|....
```

My goal:

```
|
|->root/apps/myapp
|->root/apps/readme
...
```

Also no `usr/bin`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: As a general rule, you don't want to do this. The FHS mandates location where applications should install files, and `/root` is not one of those locations. In other words, this is bad practice.

Comment: @faheem yes i know, but it was a requirement, so i had to do it.

Answer (score 2):

for everyone else with the same problem:

the line "scripts" in my setup.py-file was the bad-guy. removing this line and configuring the install-file in debian-folder is the right way to install your app where ever you want.

```
setup(name="myapp",
      version="0.80.04",
      description='My Appicantion.',
      author='ajava',
      author_email='info@ajava.de',
      url='http://http://www.ajava.de')
```